# How to lower the temperature limit of a regular NTC thermistor

Tags: voltage-divider, temperature

I am looking to make a simple circuit where i want to measure a freezer's temperature at -80 C. The problem is that most NTC thermistors i see have a low range of about -40 C. Is there a trick in designing the voltage divider to capture only low temperatures. I would accept an error of +-10C.

**I would like to use a cheap thermistor if possible**

Comment: define low? what is your simple circuit?

Comment: Why NTC? Why not choose a suitable sensor for your need?

Comment: Diodes make good temperature sensors in this range.  (there are probably other choices... platinum resistance for one.)

Comment: @winny do you have a sensor in mind that is not too expensive? <5$

Comment: Search internet/DigiKey. Questions for specific product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: A freezer that goes to -80°C can't be cheap- suggest you use a proper sensor. I have used thermocouples for temperatures to <-100°C (sperm storage), but RTDs are good too.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no *electrical* way to make a sensor measure values outside its operating range.

However, heat flow is in many ways analogous to electrical flow, so it is at least theoretically possible to create a "temperature divider" using a pair of thermal resistances. For example, you could have an insulated metal rod that has one end at the freezer temperature and the other end at ambient temperature. (Obviously, this would require drilling a hole through the wall of the freezer.) Use two thermistors, one at the ambient end and the other part way along the rod. This would allow you to extrapolate the temperature of the freezer.

Comment: +1 though you may want to add such a system introduces a thermal time lag and geometry and linear insulation so the heat only travels along the length of the rod is important.

Comment: @Trevor: As I said, "theoretically possible" -- I never meant to imply that this would be better than picking a suitable sensor in the first place.

Comment: :) yup, just adding to an already good answer